# Responsive tree diagram

Tags: html, css, diagram, responsiveness

I'm trying to make a responsive organization chart on desktop and mobile but I'm facing a problem with my code. My diagram exceeds the size of the screen and doesn't display a scroll to see the rest of the diagram as you can see on the image below. Is there a way to put my diagram in a bootstrap container and also if there is a css framework to make diagrams more easily ?

[image: my diagram is displayed on the screen]


here is the css code used as well as the html code

```css
.tree,
.tree ul,
.tree li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.tree {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.tree,
.tree ul {
  display: table;
}

.tree ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .5em 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tree li:before {
  outline: solid 1px #666;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  right: 50%;
}

.tree code,
.tree span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .2em .5em;
  padding: 3.7em .5em;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.lineh {
  margin-top: -9px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  border-top: 2px solid !important;
  width: 159px;
}

.minus-space {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}

.tree span i {
  font-size: 40px
}

.tree span.level1 {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 2em .5em !important;
}

.tree span.level2 {
  background-color: #ffcc01;
  padding: 2em .5em !important;
}

.tree span.linev {
  background-color: #666 !important;
  width: 2px !important;
  border-radius: 0% !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.tree ul:before,
.tree code:before,
.tree span:before {
  outline: solid 1px #666;
  content: "";
  height: .5em;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.tree ul:before {
  top: -.5em;
}

.tree code:before,
.tree span:before {
  top: -.55em;
}

.tree>li {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tree>li:before,
.tree>li:after,
.tree>li>code:before,
.tree>li>span:before {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="tree">
    <li><span class="level1"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Group board</b></span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="level2"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Board committees</b></span>
          <ul>
            <li> <span>Audit</span>
            </li>
            <li> <span>Remuneration and human ressources</span>
            </li>
            <li> <span class="linev"></span>
              <ul>
                <li> <span class="level2"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Compliance
                                            committees</b></span>
                </li>
                <li> <span class="linev"></span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span>Group searching</span></li>

                    <li><span>Group operation</span></li>

                    <li><span>Strategic talent</span></li>

                    <li><span>Group treasure</span></li>

                    <li><span>Group transformation</span></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <span class="level2"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Executive
                                            committees</b></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <span>Social ethics</span>
            </li>
            <li> <span>Nominations</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you for all your suggestions

Comment: did you check this out  https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/eN3Q8 ?

Comment: In your question you are mentioning wanting to make a 'genealogy diagram' (**GD**), but your code shows an 'organization chart' (**OC**). Which of the two are you planning to make? A **GD** is significantly more difficult to make as you will have branches, nodes and steps that can reconnect with their siblings or successors.

Comment: sorry it is organization chart

Comment: Why not with a js library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this answer I used some 'CSS only' flowchart code I had lying around. This code is fully responsive and designed to be multipurpose and reusable. Actually, I took the code and basically rewrote it to make it meet your requirements and more developer readable (than only me).

Instead of `UL/LI` and specific `.classes` the CSS mainly uses `<tag>` independend `data-*` attributes, which, generally speaking, have lower precedence than `.classes` making them easy to override. `data-*` attributes are also very easy to access from Javascript.

For positioning and responsiveness, the code heavily relies on **flexbox layout**.

The code is fully commented, including:

- Specifications, how to use the data attributes `data-chart`, `data-knot` ('branch','node','step') and `data-symbol`.
- Explanation of the algebra used, definition of a straight line: '**y=mx+b**', for responsiveness and scaling of `font-size`'s, `width`'s, `height`'s and spacing (`padding`, `margin`). You can find a comprehensible reference on [mathisfun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html) (no affiliate).
- Rules split after functionality (mechanism vs. styling), for easy extension and theming.
- A few tips, alternative uses, quirks (IE11).
- Some eye-candy, just because I could...

**brief summary**

- `data-chart` the type of chart used, only "OC" (Organisation Chart) for now.
- `data-knot` designates the connection type used between `data-symbols`.

  - `data-knot="branch"` (container)
  - `data-knot="node"` (horizontal line)
  - `data-knot="step"` (vertical line)
  - `data-knot="node.step"` (cross line)
- `data-symbol` container holding graphics and text depicting some organisational function. Currently only a colored circle, but can be extended to hold more content (e.g. collapsible card, its original use).
- 'Landingpage' like responsive page spacing `[band]` (8px on a 320px screen, 320px on a 1920px screen).
- Document reading direction `[dir="ltr"]` vs. `[dir="rtl"]` ready (used in `<body>`).
- Two debugging helper rules `outlines` and `hover` (used in `<body>`).

Various kinds of nesting and tree constructions are possible, the one shown here fully matches the responsive chart the OP required/requested (for as far I understood...).

Special care has been taken to fit the chart on a '360x640px' smartphone (portrait) as well as on a "1920x1200px" desktop display (landscape, my own 24").

For now, this code is ONLY available from this Stackoverflow Question. A (more elaborate) codepen version is underway...

**note**

It might well be possible that you utterly dislike what I did with the code or simply have other requirements than I interpreted. In that case do not downvote the answer, but simply ignore it, as others may find it usefull nonetheless.

**extra** 'ERS linear equations'

The online tool I created on GeoGebra, [ERS linear equations](https://www.geogebra.org/m/gct3bvsp), will hugely simplify finding the proper responsiveness equations for your CSS `calc()` functions. The tool shows 4 predefined functions of the equations used in the code. Make sure you give it a go (no affiliate, personal work, free, fork it, use it, abuse it)...

The code in the snippet was tested to work on **W10 with Chrome, Edge, Firefox and IE11 (+IE10 mode) and on Android 9+ with the default browser and Firefox**. For lack of devices, no Apple results.

```css
/******************************/
/* general global preferences */
/******************************/
html,body             { box-sizing: border-box } /* [MANDATORY] all size calcs must include padding and border */
*::before,*::after, * { box-sizing: inherit    } /* [MANDATORY], ditto, but it WILL inherit any changes */
/*
    responsive fontsize:
    p1(320,14) p2(1280,20) => 0.00625x + 12

    Assumes 16px browser default fontsize and uses
    REM to adapt to user modified font settings

    In the remainder of this <style> sheet you will find 
    an explanation of the algebra used in this document.
*/
html        { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }
body        { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; cursor: default;

              font-size: 1rem;
              font-family: Roboto,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;

              background-color: Gainsboro; color: black }

h1          { font-size: 2rem } /* Override of FF+ default nesting behaviour */

/* generic flexbox shortcuts */
[F]         { display: flex }
[R]         { flex-direction: row    } /* horizontal: row of 1:N columns (FBL default) */
[C]         { flex-direction: column } /* vertical: column of 1:N rows   */
[W]         { flex-wrap: wrap }

/* Prevents (inadverted) text selection by user (when double, double clicking) */
[no-select] { -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none; -moz-appearance : none; -webkit-appearance: none }

/* Show element outlines for debugging (use in <body> tag) */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed purple }

/* Color to show nesting level for debugging (use in <body> tag) */
[hover="1"] :not(section) :hover { background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2) }

/*
    KNOT LOGIC
    'branch' - 1:N 'node',1:N 'node.step' and 1:N 'step'
    'node'   - 1:N 'node' and 1:N 'step'
    'step'   - 1 data-symbol

    You can use flexbox shortcut attributes R (horizontal) and C (vertical) to 
    determine the nesting direction of 'branch'es and 'node's. (R) is optional
    as horizontal is the default direction. 

    (Depending on orientation of the knots, all kinds of nestings might work,
     but that will require trial and error, fiddling.)

    SPECIFICATIONS
    1) 'branch' has no specific rules, but acts as a container for 'node's
       and to distinguish from 'node' and 'step'. 
       Add your own rules for specific 'branch' styling like fonts,colors,border,spacing.

    2) 'node' and 'step' only use :before and :after to position and draw
       connecting lines.

       'node'      horizontal line attachement
       'step'      vertical
       'node.step' both

    3) 'node.step' can be empty (no 'data-symbol'), in which case it will only
       draw cross lines.

    4) 'start' and 'stop' values are used to prevent drawing of
       starting and ending lines.

    5) Knot 'lft', 'ctr' and 'rgt' values define how sibling nodes are connected
       'lft' - left hand node, only one
       'ctr' - center nodes, can be more than one 
       'rgt' - right hand node, only one

    My motivation for use of 'data-* attributes' instead of classes is they
    are easy accessible as javascript variables:

    someElement.dataset.chart
    someElement.dataset.knot
    someElement.dataset.symbol
    
*/

/***************/
/* Chart Setup */
/***************/
/* If you want the knots distributed as-is, remove 'align-items' */
[data-chart]        { display: flex; align-items: center } /* [OPTIONAL], try! */
[data-knot]         { display: flex; flex-grow: 1 }        /* [MANDATORY] */

/* default alignments */
[data-knot]         { justify-content: center }
[data-knot*="node"] { align-items: stretch    }
[data-knot*="step"] { align-items: flex-start } 

/* this code keeps the lines connect to the symbols */
[data-knot]         { position: relative; z-index: 1 } /* new stacking context */
[data-knot]:before,
[data-knot]:after   { position: absolute; z-index: -1; content: '' }
/* put some character in 'content' to keep track when debugging */

/* Horizontal lines ('node') setup */
[data-knot]:before  { top   :  1px } /* adjust -+1 for thickess of outlines */
[data-knot]:after   { bottom: -1px }

[data-knot*="node"]:before,[data-knot*="node"]:after
{ height: 0px /* for IE11 */; width: 50% }

/* Vertical lines ('step') setup */
[data-knot*="step"]:before,[data-knot*="step"]:after
{ width: 0px /* for IE11 */; left: 50%; right: 50% }

/* positioning of the lines ('lft','ctr','rgt') */
[data-knot*="ctr"]:before,[data-knot*="ctr"]:after
{ width: 100%; left: 0 }

/* (EITHER) Handles document reading direction (dir="ltr" in <body>) */
[dir="ltr"] [data-knot*="lft"]:before, [dir="ltr"] [data-knot*="lft"]:after { left : 50% }
[dir="ltr"] [data-knot*="rgt"]:before, [dir="ltr"] [data-knot*="rgt"]:after { right: 50% }
[dir="rtl"] [data-knot*="lft"]:before, [dir="rtl"] [data-knot*="lft"]:after { right: 50% }
[dir="rtl"] [data-knot*="rgt"]:before, [dir="rtl"] [data-knot*="rgt"]:after { left : 50% }

/* (OR) For use without [dir]
[data-knot*="lft"]:before, [data-knot*="lft"]:after { left : 50% }
[data-knot*="rgt"]:before, [data-knot*="rgt"]:after { right: 50% }
*/

/* line coloring */
[data-knot*="node"]:before,[data-knot*="node.step"]:after,
[data-knot*="step"]:before,[data-knot*="step"]:after { outline: 1px solid #666 }

/* no line drawing cases */
[data-knot="step"]:after, /* notice the missing '*' */
[data-knot*="start"]:before ,[data-knot*="stop"]:after { outline: none }

/*
    responsive sizes: T/B p1(320,6) p2(1280,24) and L/R p1(320,4) p2(1280,16)
    modify these to meet specific requirements.
*/
[data-knot*="step"]         { padding: 1.875vmin 1.25vmin }
[data-knot*="step"]:before  { height : 1.875vmin }              /* Same height as [data-step] T/B padding */
[data-knot*="step"]:after   { height : calc(100% - 1.875vmin) } /* pct to from below (minus T/B padding) */

/****************/
/* Symbol Setup */
/****************/
/*
    Chart 'data-symbol's, flexbox intended use

    FBL (V)     FBL (H)      Any
    --------    -------      -------
    (S)ymbol -> (H)eader  -> content
             -> (C)ontent -> content
             -> (F)ooter  -> content
*/
[data-symbol],
[data-symbol]>*         { display: flex }   /* S,H,C,F are flexbox parent containers */
[data-symbol]>*>*       { flex-grow: 1 }    /* sets default to 'fill' for content of H,C,F */

[data-symbol]           { flex-direction: column  } /* a column of 1:N rows */
[data-symbol]>.header   { align-items: center }

/* styling */
[data-symbol]           { text-decoration: none; color: currentColor; background-color: transparent }

[data-symbol]>.header {
    padding: .25rem .5rem; text-align: center; border-radius: 50%;

    /* responsive sizes: p1(320,50) p2(1920,180) */
    width : calc(8.125vmin + 24px);
    height: calc(8.125vmin + 24px);

    /*
        responsive fontsize: p1(320,6) p2(1920,20)
        Whether this works as expected depends on the minimum browser
        fontsize set by the user (content may overflow .header when set >6px)

        Tested defaults on W10:
        Edge2020 overflows, while Chrome, Firefox and IE11 do not
    */
    font-size: calc(.875vmin + 3.2px)
}

[clr="0"]       { background-color: Gainsboro; color: black }
.header,        /* .header here saves coding html */
[clr="1"]       { background-color: #fefefe; color: #1e1e1e }
[clr="2"]       { background-color: #1e1e1e; color: Yellow ; font-weight: bolder }
[clr="3"]       { background-color: #ffcc01; color: #1e1e1e; font-weight: bolder }

/**************************************/
/* Google Material Component inspired */
/**************************************/
[icon] {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center;

    /* responsive sizes: p1(320,14) p2(1280,32) */
    width      : calc(1.875vmin + 8px);
    height     : calc(1.875vmin + 8px);
    line-height: calc(1.875vmin + 8px);
    font-size  : calc(1.875vmin + 8px);
    /*
        A bit overdone for just one icon, use inline SVG instead,
        or create a small (subset) iconfont at https://icomoon.io

        icon list: https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
    */
    font-family: 'Material Icons';

    font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: normal;

    opacity: 1; /* GMC uses <1 here and 1 on :hover */

    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    font-feature-settings     : 'liga';
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing   : grayscale;
}

/******************/
/* simple banding */
/******************/
[band] { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;
         justify-content: center; align-content: center;
         padding: calc(5vh + 48px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px) }
/*
    responsive padding
    T/B: p1(320,64) p2(1920,144) => y = 0.5x   + 48
    L/R: p1(320, 8) p2(1920,320) => y = 0.195x - 54.4

    This construction keeps content nicely center aligned within
    given space.
*/
/* [OPTIONAL] */
@media screen and (max-width: 319px) { [band] { padding: 1.5rem   8px } }
@media screen and (min-width:1921px) { [band] { padding: 1.5rem 320px } }

/***********************/
/* Some extra eyecandy */
/***********************/
[data-symbol]>.header {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 1px 1px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 3px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);   /* GMC elevation 1dp */
}
[data-symbol]>.header:hover:not(:focus)  { transform: scale(1.01) }
[data-symbol]>.header:active:not(:focus) { transform: scale(0.995);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px  5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                0px 5px  8px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 14px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);  /* GMC elevation 5dp */
}
[data-symbol]>.header:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px  5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                0px 6px 10px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 18px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);  /* GMC elevation 6dp */
}
/*
    ALGEBRA for responsive sizing

    ALL responsive sizes in this document use the 'point-slope' variation
    of the 'definition of a straight line: y=mx+b':
    (https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html)

    y - y1 = y1 + m(x - x1) <=> y = y1 + m(x - x1)

    For points:
    p1 = (x1,y1) - size at minimum viewport size (x1 default  320px)
    p2 = (x2,y2) - size at maximum viewport size (x2 default 1280px)
    (using 320px and 1280px will create a full step each 160px)

    where:
    m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) ('Slope')
    x = fixed value of 100vmin, 100vh or 100vw ('X-intercept')
    b = y1 - (m * x1) ('Y-intercept')

    X-axis = viewport size
    Y-axis = element size

    Substituted equation to use:
    y = y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1)

    NOTES
    - Use VMIN for viewport width/height independed results (like fonts)
    - Use VW/VH for viewport width/height dependend results (width,height,margin,padding)
    - Do not use VMAX for x, it will yield results that are to large.

    EXTRA
    Helpfull hands-on graphical tool/demo I created on GeoGebra
    'ERS linear equations' https://www.geogebra.org/m/gct3bvsp
    (E)asy (R)esponsiveness (S)system
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body dir="ltr" no-select hover="0" outlines="0">

    <section band>
        <div data-chart="OC" C>

            <div data-knot="branch" C>
                <div data-knot="node.step.start">
                    <div data-symbol>
                        <div class="header" clr="2"><div><i icon>account_balance</i><br>Group Board</div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.step">
                    <div data-symbol>
                        <div class="header" clr="3"><div><i icon>account_balance</i><br>Board Committees</div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div data-knot="branch">
                <div data-knot="node.lft">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                         <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Audit</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Remuneration and Human Resources</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="node.step"><!-- empty data-knot for vertical line --></div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Social Ethics</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.rgt">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Nominations</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div data-knot="branch">
                <div data-knot="node.lft">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header" clr="3"><div><i icon>account_balance</i><br>Compliance Committee</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="node.step"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.rgt">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header" clr="3"><div><i icon>account_balance</i><br>Executive Committees</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div data-knot="branch">
                <div data-knot="node.lft">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                         <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Group Searching</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Group Operation</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="node.step.stop">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Group Talent</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.ctr">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Group Treasure</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-knot="node.rgt">
                    <div data-knot="step">
                        <div data-symbol>
                            <div class="header"><div>Group Transformation</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

Comment: big thanks its perfect working and it's easy to modify.

Comment: @Fabrice Fabiyi Glad to have been of service. Should you need more info or explanation, just post a comment and I'll get back to you. Also: let me know if my tool 'ERS linear equations' works for you...

Comment: just to notify you, your ERS linear equations applictaion work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin: 0 .2em .5em; padding: 3.7em .5em;` from `.tree code, .tree span` classes.

Also is you want the circle to accurate circles then remove `margin` and `padding` from the classes `level1` & `level2`.

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/XWbpzMx

```css
.tree,
.tree ul,
.tree li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.tree {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.tree,
.tree ul {
  display: table;
}

.tree ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .5em 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tree li:before {
  outline: solid 1px #666;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  right: 50%;
}

.tree code,
.tree span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.lineh {
  margin-top: -9px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  border-top: 2px solid !important;
  width: 159px;
}

.minus-space {
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}

.tree span i {
  font-size: 40px
}

.tree span.level1 {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: yellow;
}

.tree span.level2 {
  background-color: #ffcc01;
}

.tree span.linev {
  background-color: #666 !important;
  width: 2px !important;
  border-radius: 0% !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.tree ul:before,
.tree code:before,
.tree span:before {
  outline: solid 1px #666;
  content: "";
  height: .5em;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.tree ul:before {
  top: -.5em;
}

.tree code:before,
.tree span:before {
  top: -.55em;
}

.tree>li {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tree>li:before,
.tree>li:after,
.tree>li>code:before,
.tree>li>span:before {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="tree">
    <li><span class="level1"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Group board</b></span>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="level2"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Board committees</b></span>
          <ul>
            <li> <span>Audit</span>
            </li>
            <li> <span>Remuneration and human ressources</span>
            </li>
            <li> <span class="linev"></span>
              <ul>
                <li> <span class="level2"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Compliance
                      committees</b></span>
                </li>
                <li> <span class="linev"></span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span>Group searching</span></li>

                    <li><span>Group operation</span></li>

                    <li><span>Strategic talent</span></li>

                    <li><span>Group treasure</span></li>

                    <li><span>Group transformation</span></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <span class="level2"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><br><b>Executive <br> committees</b></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <span>Social ethics</span>
            </li>
            <li> <span>Nominations</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```